# Observable pipes

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators, rxjs-observables

I have a question about the pipes of the observables

suppose I have the following code:

```
const skip$ = of(4);
const length$ = of(24);
const schoolId$ = of(1);

const source = combineLatest(skip$, length$, schoolId$).pipe(
  map(([skip, length]) => `skip: ${skip}, length: ${length}`),
  map(text => text ) // I need now schoolId, how can i get
);
```

in the second map i need the schoolId. How can i get the schoolId without doing this:

```
const source = combineLatest(skip$, length$, schoolId$).pipe(
  map(([skip, length, schoolId]) => ({text: `skip: ${skip}, length: ${length}`, schoolId})),
  map(text => `${text.text}, schoolId: ${text.schoolId}` )
);
```

here you have the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ah5mpp) to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all things ReactiveX, you've got a lot of options. Maybe the closest to what you've got now would be to use [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom)...

```js
const source = combineLatest(skip$, length$).pipe(
  map(([skip, length]) => (`skip: ${skip}, length: ${length}`)),
  withLatestFrom(schoolId$),
  map(([text, schoolId]) => `${text}, schoolId: ${schoolId}` )
);
```